# Rspec test reuse code for before_filter and method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

Consider following example (controller):

```
MyController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @objects = Object.fancy_way_of_retrieval
      @properties = Property.fancy_way_of_retrieval_two

      @something_else = @objects.do_something
    end

    def another_method
      @something_other = SomethingOther.get_values
      @objects = Object.fancy_way_of_retrieval
      @properties = Property.fancy_way_of_retrieval_two
    end
  end
```

First thing I did is to move the duplicate code in the `before_filter`

```
MyController < ApplicationController 
before_filter :set_variables

  def index
    @something_else = @objects.do_something
  end

  def another_method
    @something_other = SomethingOther.get_values
  end

private
  def set_variables
    @objects = Object.fancy_way_of_retrieval
    @properties = Property.fancy_way_of_retrieval_two
  end
end
```

Which looks better, right? Now on to the test :

```
describe 'before filters' do
  let(:objects) { [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:object)] }
  let(:properties) { [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:property)] }

  before do
    allow(Object).to receive(:fancy_way_of_retrieval).and_return { objects } 
    allow(Property).to receive(:fancy_way_of_retrieval_two).and_return { properties } 
  end

  it 'assigns objects' do
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:objects)).to eq(objects)
  end

  it 'assigns properties' do
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:properties)).to eq(properties)
  end
end
```

Now onto the controller action method test :

```
describe '#index' do
  let(:objects) { [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:object)] }
  let(:properties) { [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:property)] }

  before do
    allow(Object).to receive(:fancy_way_of_retrieval).and_return { objects } 
    allow(Property).to receive(:fancy_way_of_retrieval_two).and_return { properties } 
  end

  it 'asssigns something else' do
  ....
  end
end
```

See I had to write the `let` and `before` blocks for `objects` and `properties` stubs for both before filter method and the controller action method, in order for test to pass. Because the `@something_else` uses the `@objects` instance variable.

How do I do this without repeating this bit of code?